# A character with a dark background seeking redemption or an average character background, what is more thematically appropriate?

Tags: characters, backstory

This project is a sort of an attempt to deconstruct some tropes in fiction.

The story follows a Valkotr, it is a title, whom is tasked by the emperor of the *evil* empire to hunt down a chosen one party and bring them to justice. The Valktor is fairly smart and capable but the pesky teenagers group always manages to allude him because of basically magical elements that work in their favor giving them a deus ex machina after another.

Since I'm going for this theme here is what I'm thinking so far about this aspect. **Remember this is just between us and won't make it to the pages like that, this is to make it easier for you and lets be honest it's not like I will ever get published.**
While I use the word evil here I have made it really practical and overall very beneficial to people. Sure it is an absolute monarchy but things are far superiors to the older feudal ways in every regard.
The whole chosen one thing is actually an ancient demonic pact between the last remaining nobility who plotted against the emperor since he did not like them. Did not like this in the murdered all nobility not the kind of not invite them to your party.
However they got screwed in the timeline since the chosen one appeared 300 after the last noble died, I mean why would they trust demons is beyond me. The chosen one party is actually altruistic idiots and brainwashed to believe that the empire is evil and they need to overthrow it to free people.

Now the part I'm struggling with is the background to the Valktor guy.
I have 1 of 2 main ideas.

### Dark past

Coming from islands faraway from the empire he is turned  into banditry and violence until one day he is disgusted enough with himself that he decides to commit suicide.

By chance he is rescued by the imperial guard and gets to meet the big guy himself. He looks into his soul and somehow gives him and purpose and is all like: "Better to seek redemption than oblivion"

### Average past

A son of a merchant wealthy guy that wastes his life away in pleasures and idling around.
You traditional sins and stuff here apply. Lots of drinking and whoring and gambling and even occasional violence from time to time.

I'll figure out a way for him to meet the emperor. But it should follow the same rules.

### What I'm struggling with is what fits the themes more and why?

*Coming from such darkness to seek redemption enforcing that the empire is actually pretty decent?*

*Or absolute hedonist pursuits without meaning until he meets the big guy?*

Comment: Personally, I found the "dark past" version more interesting, but it really all comes down to what story you want to write and why. Either version could be done well or poorly --I don't see one necessarily fitting better with the concept than the other.

Answer (score 1):

Both are interesting...  I could even see a "buddy cop"... a buddy Valktor if you will... dynamic between someone with the first backstory and someone with the second back story.

The former could be from a band of Robin Hood merry men styled gang that have honor among thieves.  They rob only the rich, give it to the poor, and never kill unless in self-defense.   The hero breaks these rules and gets tossed from the gang (either they tell him to leave OR they try to kill him).   Either way, he's saved by the guard who convince him he can still help the poor unfortunate souls if he joins.

The latter could be a guy who comes from a rich family with poor disipline over him.  A spoiled child who always got his way until one day something shatters his party boy persona.   He could be cut off from by his parents after one too many stunts OR could be a victim of the very band of teens (maybe his father was a successful merchant of produce... say cabbages... and these brainwashed children ended up wrecking his shop/cart/livelihood while being chased by the kings guard.  Maybe the cart wreck killed the merchant father in the process?).   Personally, I think his conversion is the simple realization that his "friends" were only friends with him for his money, or his friends and family all think he is a disgrace that will never amount to anything...   depersonalize the conflict with those meddling kids and their animal companion that can do things that seem unatural for that type of creature... He's not after them for something personal... he's showing he can be a hero.